# Empty a file without grep subsequently treating it like a binary file

Tags: shell, text-processing, grep

Currently I have `netcat` piping output to `tee` which is writing to output.txt with

```
nc -l -k -p 9100 | tee output.txt
```

I want to monitor this output, so I'm watching it with `tail -f | egrep -i 'regex'` via PuTTY so that I only see relevant bits.

Every now and then I want to clear the output file. The issue arises that if I do `> output.txt` and then again try to `tail -f | egrep ...` I get no output.  If I grep through the file, I get no matches, despite knowing that there *should* be matches (as `cat output.txt` spits out the file properly)

```
mitch@quartz:~$ grep output.txt -e 'regex'
Binary file output.txt matches
```

While the same command on output.txt *before* emptying it works fine.

Basically: `>` makes `grep` think my file is a  binary file and it won't properly search. Is there a better way to clear the file?

Comment: Instead of `> output.txt` why not try something along the lines of `echo Start > output.txt`.  Hopefully, `grep` won't think it's a binary file.

Comment: Best would be to use `tee -a`. See [there](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150179/22565) for details (`tee -a` is the equivalent of shells using `>>`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I think that's the best answer in this thread

Comment: If you truncate the file while open, the next write (by `| tee`) will refill it with zeros and the write will occur at the previous offset. `grep` treats an occurrence of 0 within the first buffer read (32kiB) as a binary file by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only problem is that `grep` treats it as binary, tell `grep` to search it regardless:

```
$ head /bin/bash > out
$ echo "test" >> out 
$ grep test out 
Binary file out matches
$ grep -a test out 
test
```

From `man grep`:

```
   -a, --text
          Process  a binary file as if it were text; this is equivalent to
          the --binary-files=text option.
```

Answer (score 3):

It might answer your question, so here are the results of a few tests I just ran:

```
$ > output.txt
$ file output.txt
output.txt: empty

$ echo "" > output.txt
$ file output.txt
output.txt: very short file (no magic)

$ echo " " > output.txt
$ file output.txt
output.txt : ASCII text
```

As you can see, the file isn't categorised the same way according to what you actually *"put*" in it when you try to clear it. Therefore, you might want to use an empty string instead of just nothing.

Comment: I'll give it a shot in a minute and report back

Comment: It works, but only if it's ASCII beforehand. That is, if I had previously done `>  output` and then `echo " " > output` it still gets seen as a binary file

Comment: The difference between the three is that the first is empty, the second contains a newline (not really an empty string) and the third contains a space and a newline.

Answer (score 3):

`>` makes grep think the file is binary because it is binary. The thing is, you emptied the file, but didn't stop the program that was filling it.

`>output.txt` creates `output.txt` if it doesn't exist, and truncates it to zero length if it does.

At the point you run `>output.txt`, there is a `tee` process which has the file open. Truncating the file doesn't affect the position at which `tee` is writing. Let's say it had written *N* bytes before the truncation. The next time `tee` writes after the truncation, it will start writing at position *N*. Writing at a position beyond the current end of a file is allowed and fills the beginning of the file with null bytes.¹ That's what happened here.

Grep sees a file that begins with some null bytes. It correctly reports the file as binary.

You can tell GNU grep to treat the file as text by calling `grep -a`. It will search the whole file, including the null bytes (which don't match, so they don't affect the result unless there's a match on the first line, but they may cause a slowdown if there are a lot of them).

A better solution is to tell `tee` to always write at the current end of the file. Fortunately (as [Stephane Chazelas remarked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162260/empty-a-file-without-grep-subsequently-treating-it-like-a-binary-file#comment265795_162260)), there's an option for that: `tee -a` (present on all POSIX-compliant systems). You'll need to truncate the file first.

```
>output.txt
nc -l -k -p 9100 | tee -a output.txt
```

¹  <sub>Most filesystems allow blocks that would entirely consist of null bytes to remain unallocated. This specialized method of compression is called making a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).</sub>